# Correct syntax/format for MySQL Trigger with Date Criteria

Tags: mysql, date, triggers

I'm trying to create a trigger that tests if a 'request' is made before a specific date and if so sets the flag to 'YES', else 'NO'.

But PHPMyAdmin just keeps telling me there's an error, the full trigger is already active and working, so I've not included the rest of it.  It is just this snippet that needs correcting:

I'm presuming there is an issue with the formatting of the IF statement/date criteria:

```
IF NEW.RequestDate < '2012-07-12 00:00:00' THEN
    SET NEW.flagReqPreJulyTwelfthTwentyTwelve="YES";
ELSE
    SET NEW.flagReqPreJulyTwelfthTwentyTwelve="NO";    
END IF;
```

Comment: Please show the whole trigger.

Comment: And what error do you get?

Comment: The rest of the trigger is not the issue as it works fine and is just other IF ElSE ENDIF statements.  My issue (I believe) is the formatting of the date criteria above.  Can you comment on this please.

Comment: It is just a generic error message: [ One or more errors have occurred while processing your request:

    The following query has failed: ]

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't change 
NEW.flagReqPreJulyTwelfthTwentyTwelve.
Why don't you use a local variable and insert that value into your table like this:

```
IF NEW.RequestDate < '2012-07-12 00:00:00' THEN
    SET myvar="YES";
ELSE
    SET myvar="NO";    
END IF;
```

Comment: I've discovered that it won't work in a BEFORE INSERT, but it does in a BEFORE UPDATE, not quite sure, but it works now, thanks.